# Access Violation Violation Location With Low Numbers

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for school. The code is supposed to read form a file and create an array, then sort the values of the array to output certain info. It works just fine as long as I have 3+ lines of info in the file. If not, I get the following error:

> First-chance exception at 0x01305876 in Homework11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcd71b288.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x01305876 in Homework11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcd71b288.

I can't figure out why, any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream> //calls the information needed
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; //sets all unmarked commands to std::

const int ARRSIZE = 1000;

struct Student
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string id, temp;
    double gpa;
};

int readArray(ifstream& ifile, Student arr[]);
void swapElements(Student arr[], int i, int j);
void sortArray(Student arr[], int numberInTheArray);

int main()
{ // Declares the needed variables
    double sought, min, max;
    int i, ival, returnvar, count = 0, mincount, maxcount;
    string filename;
    ifstream ifile;
    Student arr[ARRSIZE];

    cout << "Input File Name: ";//requesting the file name
    cin >> filename;

    ifile.open(filename.c_str());//opening the file

    if (!ifile)//checking if it opened or not
    {
        cout << endl << "That file does not exist!" << endl;//informing the user it did
        return 1;//not open and returning 1
    }

    cout << "Which number do you want to return? ";//requesting the desired number
    cin >> ival;
    i = ival - 1;
    cout << endl;

    returnvar = readArray(ifile, arr);

    min = arr[0].gpa;
    max = arr[0].gpa;
    sought = arr[0].gpa;

    while (count < returnvar)
    {
        if (arr[count].gpa < min)
        {
            min = arr[count].gpa;
            mincount = count;
        }

        if (arr[count].gpa > max)
        {
            max = arr[count].gpa;
            maxcount = count;
        }

        if (count == i)
        {
            sought = arr[count].gpa;
        }

        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "The file is empty!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    cout << "Before Sort:" << endl;
    cout << " Min GPA is " << min << " for " << arr[mincount].lastName << "." << endl;
    cout << " Max GPA is " << max << " for " << arr[maxcount].lastName << "." << endl;


    if (returnvar < ARRSIZE)
    {
        cout << " WARNING: Only " << returnvar << " numbers were read into the array!" << endl;
    }

    if (i >= returnvar)
    {
        cout << " There aren't that many numbers in the array!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (i > ARRSIZE)
    {
        cout << " " << i << " is bigger than " << ARRSIZE << "!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (i < returnvar)
    {
        cout << " Value " << ival << " is " << sought << " for " << arr[i].lastName << "." << endl << endl;
    }

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    sortArray(arr, returnvar);

    count = 0;

    while (count < returnvar)
    {
        if (arr[count].gpa < min)
        {
            min = arr[count].gpa;
            mincount = count;
        }

        if (arr[count].gpa > max)
        {
            max = arr[count].gpa;
            maxcount = count;
        }

        if (count == i)
        {
            sought = arr[count].gpa;
        }

        count++;
    }

    cout << "After Sort:" << endl;
    cout << " Array[0] GPA is " << min << " for " << arr[0].lastName << "." << endl;
    cout << " Array[" << (returnvar - 1) << "] GPA is " << max << " for " << arr[(returnvar - 1)].lastName << "." << endl;

    if (returnvar < ARRSIZE)
    {
        cout << " WARNING: Only " << returnvar << " numbers were read into the array!" << endl;
    }

    if (i >= returnvar)
    {
        cout << " There aren't that many numbers in the array!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (i > ARRSIZE)
    {
        cout << " " << i << " is bigger than " << ARRSIZE << "!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (i < returnvar)
    {
        cout << " Value " << ival << " is " << sought << " for " << arr[i].lastName << "." << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int readArray(ifstream& ifile, Student arr[])
{
    int counter = 0;

    while ((ifile) && (counter <= ARRSIZE))
    {
        ifile >> arr[counter].firstName;
        ifile >> arr[counter].lastName;
        ifile >> arr[counter].id;
        ifile >> arr[counter].gpa;

        counter++;
    }

    return (counter - 1);
}

void sortArray(Student arr[], int numberInTheArray)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberInTheArray - 1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < numberInTheArray - 1; j++) 
        {
            if ( arr[j].gpa > arr[j + 1].gpa)
            {
                swapElements(arr, j, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void swapElements(Student arr[], int i, int j)
{
    Student temp;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Please ignore the insanity and comments. Like I said, for an entry level course.

Comment: A sample of the data file would probably help, as well as the platform, though it appears to be Windows. Are yo using Visual Studio? Further, that exception should trip the debugger and give you a call stack telling you fairly closely where the wheels fell off. VS has an outstanding debugger. And, if `readArray` is supposed to do what it appears, it should probably look [more like this](http://pastebin.com/TdFJV5N1). I'll be honest. For an entry-level course your code is *easy* to peruse. Either your instructor is stellar, you're fastidious about your code, or likely some of both.

Comment: In addition to the above, I'd strongly suggest you go over you code and ensure nowhere are you accessing your array outside of `0..(returnvar-1))`. Remember, array indexes in C++ are 0-based, so an array of N items has a top-end index of (N-1).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `counter <= ARRSIZE` with `counter < ARRSIZE` (a rule of thumb in C is: never use `<=` in operations related to container sizes).

EDIT: also in your main(), you must check that `i < ARRSIZE` (equivalently, return error if `i >= ARRSIZE`). At present you seem to accept the case `i == ARRSIZE`, which is also wrong. And finally, `readArray` should return `counter` (that is, one more than the last written index).

Comment: And in case you're wondering why C counts the indexes in this way: [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) the paper that probably had a role estabilishing this convention: